# MVC Ajax Form for Editable Table Row

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following partial view

```
@model Marks.Web.ViewModels.AssignmentMarkViewModel

<div class="table">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_MarkInlineEditor", "Semesters", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "editor" + Model.AssignmentId
    }, new { @id = "editor" + Model.AssignmentId, @class = "tr" }))
    {
        <span class="td">@Model.AssignmentName</span>
        <span class="td">@(Model.Mark.HasValue ? Model.Mark.Value.ToString("#.##") : "")</span>
        <span class="td">@Model.Weight.ToString("#.##")</span>
        <span class="td">@(Model.ActualMark.HasValue ? Model.ActualMark.Value.ToString("#.##") : "")</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AssignmentId)
        <span class="td"><button type="submit" name="option" value="edit">Edit</button></span>
        <span class="td"><button type="submit" name="option" value="clear">Clear</button></span>
    }
</div>
```

When clicking the Edit button, the action method returns this other partial view, which serves as the editing view:

```
@model Marks.Web.ViewModels.AssignmentMarkViewModel

<div class="table">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_MarkInlineViewer", "Semesters", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "viewer" + Model.AssignmentId
    }, new { @id = "viewer" + Model.AssignmentId, @class = "tr" }))
    {
        <span class="td">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AssignmentName)</span>
        <span class="td">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mark)</span>
        <span class="td">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Weight, new { required="required", type="number" })</span>
        <span class="td">xx</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AssignmentId)
        <span class="td"><button type="submit" name="option" value="save">Save</button></span>
        <span class="td"><button type="submit" name="option" value="cancel">Cancel</button></span>
    }
</div>
```

When I click the Save button, the action method called should be `_MarkInlineViewer` but it instead calls `_MarkInlineEditor`. Is there something wrong with how I'm doing this? Here are the action methods:

```
public PartialViewResult _MarkInlineEditor(string option, int assignmentId)
{
    var marksRepo = new MarksRepo();
    var mark = marksRepo.GetMarkById(assignmentId);
    var markVm = Mapper.Map<AssignmentMarkViewModel>(mark);
    return PartialView(option == "edit" ? "_MarkInlineEditor" : "_MarkInlineViewer", markVm);
}

public PartialViewResult _MarkInlineViewer(AssignmentMarkViewModel amvm)
{
    var marksRepo = new MarksRepo();
    var mark = Mapper.Map<AssignmentMark>(amvm);
    var updatedMark = marksRepo.UpdateMark(mark);
    var updatedAmvm = Mapper.Map<AssignmentMarkViewModel>(updatedMark);

    return PartialView("_MarkInlineViewer", updatedAmvm);
}
```

Comment: you cannot nest forms tags

Comment: I know that, is that what it's doing here? I thought it'd replace the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can't replace the form I'm working with like I was trying to do here, so for my `UpdateTargetId` I used the parent div instead of the form's ID.